# Sorting went fail for array

Tags: magento2.3.1, array, sort

I am having the array of color attribute options...

I would like to sort the array based on 'store0' key...

I have used multisort and usort but its not working

```
[821] => Array
    (
        [checked] => 
        [intype] => radio
        [id] => 969
        [sort_order] => 513
        [store1] => Yellow
        [defaultswatch1] => 
        [swatch1] => 
        [store0] => Yellow - KID
        [defaultswatch0] => 
        [swatch0] => 
    )

[822] => Array
    (
        [checked] => 
        [intype] => radio
        [id] => 207
        [sort_order] => 309
        [store1] => Yellow Beige - Chroma 1 ½
        [defaultswatch1] => 
        [swatch1] => 
        [store0] => Yellow Beige - Chroma 1 ½
        [defaultswatch0] => 
        [swatch0] => 
    )

[823] => Array
    (
        [checked] => 
        [intype] => radio
        [id] => 857
        [sort_order] => 403
        [store1] => Yellow
        [defaultswatch1] => 
        [swatch1] => 
        [store0] => Yellow-RAIN HAT BOB
        [defaultswatch0] => 
        [swatch0] => 
    )

[824] => Array
    (
        [checked] => 
        [intype] => radio
        [id] => 860
        [sort_order] => 406
        [store1] => Yellow
        [defaultswatch1] => 
        [swatch1] => 
        [store0] => Yellow-WOMEN
        [defaultswatch0] => 
        [swatch0] => 
    )

[825] => Array
    (
        [checked] => 
        [intype] => radio
        [id] => 851
        [sort_order] => 400
        [store1] => Yellow
        [defaultswatch1] => 
        [swatch1] => 
        [store0] => Yellow-WOMEN1
        [defaultswatch0] => 
        [swatch0] => 
    )

[826] => Array
    (
        [checked] => 
        [intype] => radio
        [id] => 29
        [sort_order] => 310
        [store1] => Zebra
        [defaultswatch1] => 
        [swatch1] => 
        [store0] => Zebra
        [defaultswatch0] => 
        [swatch0] => 
    )

[827] => Array
    (
        [checked] => 
        [intype] => radio
        [id] => 1383
        [sort_order] => 830
        [store1] => abstract
        [defaultswatch1] => 
        [swatch1] => 
        [store0] => abstract
        [defaultswatch0] => 
        [swatch0] => 
    )

[828] => Array
    (
        [checked] => 
        [intype] => radio
        [id] => 1382
        [sort_order] => 829
        [store1] => caol color
        [defaultswatch1] => 
        [swatch1] => 
        [store0] => caol color
        [defaultswatch0] => 
        [swatch0] => 
    )

[829] => Array
    (
        [checked] => 
        [intype] => radio
        [id] => 1381
        [sort_order] => 829
        [store1] => cool color
        [defaultswatch1] => 
        [swatch1] => 
        [store0] => cool color
        [defaultswatch0] => 
        [swatch0] => 
    )
```

Comment: I know its a simple question .. but something went wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the example, you can use this](https://sohel.dev/2014/03/11/multi-dimensional-array-sort-by-value-in-php/)

```
function asc_sort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter = array();
    $ret = array();
    reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii] = $va[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii] = $array[$ii];
    }
    $array = $ret;
}
asc_sort($a_array, "store0");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = your array from above;

usort(
    $arr, 
    function($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a['store0'], $b['store0']);
    }
);
```

the `usort` function receives the first parameter by reference. So after the code above you can just iterate through `$arr`. It should be ordered by the `store0` field.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = your_array;

function compareOrder($x, $y)
{
  return $x['store0'] - $y['store0'];
}
usort($array, 'compareOrder');
```